# Can we simulate 3fingers or 4fingers tap on iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

My app need tap 3 or 4 fingers at the same time and I need to simulate it.

Can we simulate that on simulator or just test on real device?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must test on a real device for this. The simulator only does 1 finger taps/swipes or 2 finger pinch/zoom.

There are so many other differences that you must test on a real device eventually anyway.